# URL redirection JSF

Tags: jsf-2, prettyfaces

I have my my app `url`: `127.0.0.1:8080/reader/read.xhtml`
    The `read.xhtml` is populated thorough database and has got various 
    links which are hard coded in database. *(read.xhtml is actually 
    retrieved as String from DB.)* 
for e.g. there are links 
    `(<a href ="/write.xhtml>write</a>)
        /write.xhtml
        /upload.xhtml`
as I cannot add the context when i click the link it directs me to 
    `WWW://127.0.0.1:8080/write.xhtml` or 
    `HTTP://127.0.0.1:8080/upload.xhtml`

Is there any way I can redirect the link to 
    `HTTP://127.0.0.1:8080/reader/write.xhtml`.
    Can Prettyfaces handle this. If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the context path to the links by rendering it in front of your links. Something like:

```
<a href="#{request.contextPath}/#{someBean.linkFromDatabase}">write</a>
```

Comment: Cant do that as the link is acquired from the database. Its something which is hardcoded

Comment: Yeah, but you can use multiple EL expressions to render the link. I updated my answer...